# How to convert a date String to a Date or Calendar object?

Tags: java, date, calendar

I have a `String` representation of a date that I need to create a `Date` or `Calendar` object from. I've looked through `Date` and `Calendar` APIs but haven't found anything that can do this other than creating my own ugly parse method. I know there must be a way, does anyone know of a solution?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 126, accepted):

In brief:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
try {
  Date date = formatter.parse("01/29/02");
} catch (ParseException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

See [`SimpleDateFormat` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more.

And to turn it into a `Calendar`, do:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);
```

Comment: What if the original string can either be MM/dd/yy of yy/MM/dd?

Comment: Cristina I am also facing the same problem. I don't know what format is send by server. Now @Matt Sheppard do you have any suggestion for that.

Answer (score 15):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse( "2015-01-02" )
```

## java.time

Java 8 and later has a new [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework that makes these other answers outmoded. This framework is inspired by [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), defined by [JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), and extended by the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project. See the [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/TOC.html).

The old bundled classes, java.util.Date/.Calendar, are notoriously troublesome and confusing. Avoid them.

## `LocalDate`

Like Joda-Time, java.time has a class [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) to represent a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

## ISO 8601

If your input string is in the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format of `yyyy-MM-dd`, you can ask that class to directly parse the string with no need to specify a formatter.

The ISO 8601 formats are used by default in java.time, for both parsing and generating string representations of date-time values.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( "2015-01-02" );
```

## Formatter

If you have a different format, specify a formatter from the [java.time.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/package-summary.html) package. You can either specify your own formatting pattern or let java.time automatically localize as appropriate to a `Locale` specifying a human language for translation and cultural norms for deciding issues such as period versus comma.

### Formatting pattern

Read the [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class doc for details on the codes used in the format pattern. They vary a bit from the old outmoded `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` class patterns.

Note how the second argument to the `parse` method is a [method reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html), syntax added to Java 8 and later.

```
String input = "January 2, 2015";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "MMMM d, yyyy" , Locale.US );
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse ( input , formatter );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "localDate: " + localDate );
```

> localDate: 2015-01-02

### Localize automatically

Or rather than specify a formatting pattern, let java.time localize for you. Call `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate`, and be sure to specify the desired/expected `Locale` rather than rely on the JVM’s current default which can change at any moment during runtime(!).

```
String input = "January 2, 2015";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate ( FormatStyle.LONG );
formatter = formatter.withLocale ( Locale.US );
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse ( input , formatter );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "input: " + input + " | localDate: " + localDate );
```

> input: January 2, 2015 | localDate: 2015-01-02

Comment: Excellent overview! This answer should be accepted.

Answer (score 9):

The **highly regarded [Joda Time library](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/index.html)** is also worth a look.  This is basis for the new [date and time api](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) that is pencilled in for Java 7.  The design is neat, intuitive, [well documented](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html) and avoids a lot of the clumsiness of the original `java.util.Date` / `java.util.Calendar` classes.

Joda's [`DateFormatter`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) can parse a String to a Joda `DateTime`.

Comment: While Joda-Time was hugely successful as the first good date-time library, the Joda-Time team now advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DateFormat.parse(String)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `DateFormat` class has a `parse` method.

See [DateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) for more information.