# How to convert ISO 8601 date (string) to Date?

Tags: java, date, parsing, iso8601

I am parsing XML file. In this file there is one tag containing date string `"2008-11-10T05:51:33Z"` and I want convert this string in to `java.util.Date object.`

How can this be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a date String to a Date or Calendar object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43802/how-to-convert-a-date-string-to-a-date-or-calendar-object)

Comment: FYI, the format of this string is defined by the [*ISO 8601* standard](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Answer (score 9):

Use [java.text.DateFormat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) - or more likely, [SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Alternatively, go for [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) with its infinitely better API. Be careful with the Java built-in APIs - DateFormats aren't thread-safe. (They are in Joda Time, which uses immutable types almost everywhere.)

An (untested - should be fine except for *possibly* the timezone bit) example for the Joda Time API:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
DateTime dt = fmt.parse("2008-11-10T05:51:33Z");
```

Comment: One thing to note about Joda time, if you're writing mobile or embedded apps it is HUGE (like 500k).

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.parse( "2008-11-10T05:51:33Z" )
```

## Using java.time

The modern approach uses the java.time classes. Avoid the troublesome older date-time classes such as `Date` and `Calendar` as they are now supplanted by java.time classes.

### ISO 8601

Your input string complies with the ISO 8601 standard for formatting strings representing date-time values. The java.time classes use the standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings, so no need to specify a formatting pattern.

The `Z` on the end is short for `Zulu` and means UTC.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2008-11-10T05:51:33Z" ) ;
```

### `java.util.Date`

Best to avoid the old legacy class `java.util.Date`. But if you must, you can convert to/from java.time by calling new methods added to the old classes. Here we use [`Date.from`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#from-java.time.Instant-).

```
java.util.Date d = java.util.Date.from( instant ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dateToGetFromString;

dateToGetFromString = DateTime.Parse(stringContainingDate);
```

You can also use the TryParse function of DateTime class, look in the documentation.

Comment: You can delete your Answer.