# Convert a string to a GregorianCalendar

Tags: java, string, gregorian-calendar

How do a I take an input birthday string such as 02 26 1991 and make it into a Gregorian Calendar?

I tried parsing it first but it keeps giving me an error message so I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. I also have other input data before this date. One is another string and one is a double value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a date String to a Date or Calendar object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43802/how-to-convert-a-date-string-to-a-date-or-calendar-object)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to parse the date and then assign it to a [`Calendar`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy");
Date date = df.parse("02 26 1991");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
```

The third line could be replaced with:

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
```

but I prefer the first version.

Comment: FYI: This doesn't handle the time zone.

Answer (score 1):

Use a DateFormat as shown [here](http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/how-do-i-parse-a-java-string-that-specifies-a-date):

Example:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm dd/MM/yy");
dateFormat.setLenient(false);
Date d = dateFormat.parse("06:23 01/05/06");
```

> Use the parse() method of the SimpleDateFormat class. You can use setLenient(false) to force strict parsing.