# how to convert a string(Date) to gregorian calendar in android

Tags: android, datetime, simpledateformat, gregorian-calendar

I have a string like 14-9-2014,I want to convert it as gregorian calendar,I have searched and tried lot many ways but i cant get any solution,So can any one please tell me how to conver it?thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a string to a GregorianCalendar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331513/convert-a-string-to-a-gregoriancalendar)

Answer (score 3):

Use SimpleDateFormat to parse the date and then assign it to a Calendar.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy");
Date date = df.parse("14-9-2014");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
```

The third line could be replaced with:

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy", context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale);

Date date = formatter.parse("14-9-2014");
Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
c.setTime(date);
```