# Simple way to convert "yyyyMMdd"-formatted string into a GregorianCalendar object

Tags: java, android

I see plenty of questions for taking a GregorianCalendar or Date object and printing a "yyyyMMdd"-formatted string.

However, I want to go the opposite direction.

I have a "yyyyMMdd"-formatted string, and I want to create a GregorianCalendar object.

I could easily parse this and call a series of `.set()` methods, but I was wondering if there was a slick-and-easy way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999172/how-to-parse-a-date http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496359/how-to-parse-date-string-to-date and lots of other links show up in a Web search on `java parse date`.

Comment: Your exact question has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331513/convert-a-string-to-a-gregoriancalendar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `SimpleDateFormat` like so:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
Date date = format.parse("20150119");
Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);
```