# How can I split string using Regular Expression(Pattern)?

Tags: java

I want to split my String (e.g. "20150101") using Regular Expression.

 For example I need these values: "2015","01","01"

Comment: Use `String.split(String regex)`? There are tons of questions on SO about using regex. What have you tried?

Comment: Aren't you actually trying to parse this as a date instead? See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28034202/simple-way-to-convert-yyyymmdd-formatted-string-into-a-gregoriancalendar-objec

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String pattern = "(....)(..)(..)";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(inputString);//inputString:"20150101"
```

Now you can use `m.group(x)` to get the parts of the string. For example:

`m.group(1)` is first four digit ("2015" in your question).

Comment: Are you sure it's not `m.group(0)` for the first group?

Comment: group 0 is always the entire match

Answer (score 3):

Bit hard to say without more details, but try:

```
(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})
```

Your [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher)'s three captured [group](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29) references will then have the values you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just combining the two answers both are valid

First

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            String input = "20150101";
            String pattern = "(....)(..)(..)";
            Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
            Matcher m = r.matcher(input);       
            m.find();
            for(int i=1;i<=m.groupCount();i++){
                String token = m.group( i ); 
                  System.out.println(token);
            }
    }
```

Second

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            String input = "20150101";
            String pattern = "(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})";
            Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
            Matcher m = r.matcher(input);       
            m.find();
            for(int i=1;i<=m.groupCount();i++){
                String token = m.group( i ); 
                  System.out.println(token);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final Pattern DATE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^([\\d]{4})([\\d]{2})([\\d]{2})$");

public static Optional<String[]> split(String str) {
    final Matcher matcher = DATE_PATTERN.matcher(str);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        final String[] array = new String[3];
        array[0] = matcher.group(1);
        array[1] = matcher.group(2);
        array[2] = matcher.group(3);
        return Optional.of(array);
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```