# The Date(String) is deprecated

Tags: java, date, deprecated

My `Date` constructor is *deprecated* and highlighted in Yellow.

How can I use `Calendar.Set()` to resolve this issue. I have called both `import java.util.Calendar`; and `date`.

Code is below. Thanks in advance.

```
Format f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
Date d = new Date(f.format(geoState.getString("fireTime")));
temp.setFireTime(d);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a string to a GregorianCalendar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331513/convert-a-string-to-a-gregoriancalendar)

Comment: In the future, if you have trouble with a class, the first thing you should do is read that class's documentation.  The [documentation for the Date class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) is very clear about the replacements for its deprecated methods and constructors.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `DateFormat.parse` method to convert a `String` to `Date`

```
String string = "January 2, 2010";
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date = format.parse(string);
System.out.println(date);
```

In your case it will be something like this

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
Date date = format.parse(geoState.getString("fireTime"));
temp.setFireTime(date);
```

Comment: Thank you Mauricio for your help.

Comment: So I should do this way. Format f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
Date d= f.parse(geoState.getString("fireTime"));

AND this what it has been suggested Date date =((DateFormat) f).parse(geoState.getString("fireTime"));

Comment: @androidlive please provide me with your string. And avoid using single lines that are hard to read in code

Comment: Sorry, Mauricio, how I can post it so that I does not get in a line. Thanks for your help. I tried to separate lines but still goes to one line.

Comment: @androidlive I dont mean here. I mean in your code always make it clear what is going on

Comment: Ok, got it. if (t != null && !t.equals("") && !t.equals("null")) {
          Format f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
           Date d = new Date(f.format(geoState.getString("fireTime")));
 temp.setFireTime(d);
}

Comment: The string is keep changing and here is the other part of it.
t = geoState.getString("timeStateChanged");
       if (t != null && !t.equals("") && !t.equals("null")) {
        Format f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
        Date d = new Date(f.format(geoState.getString("fireTime")));
        temp.setTimeStateChanged(d);
       }

Comment: @androidlive I have updated my answer. is `format.parse` not `format.format`

Comment: part of my task and focus is to fix the deprecated sections of the code. The code has been written by someone else. I am a newbie and thanks for your support and help.

Comment: @androidlive we are/were newbies at any moment, if you continue to look for better ways, pattern and follow the best practices you will refactor that and make it readable and maintainable

Comment: Correct. Thanks. I am working on that. The message gives me an error. Unhandled exception type PraseException on  this line :  Date date = format.parse(geoState.getString("fireTime"));

Comment: @Please update your question and include the contents of `geoState.getString("fireTime")`

Comment: Ok, sure. I will update my code to include the output of `geoState.getString("fireTime")`

Comment: the output is different each time and I don't have access to it right now. It is string that would be changed to date. I applied your suggestion and that gives me ParseException type error. I am trying to get rid of the deprecated Date() method.  `Date d = new Date(f.format(geoState.getString("fireTime")));`

Comment: @androidlive I need any example since the format has to match the input

Comment: I was able to fix it by adding a try catch because of the parse. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi again, I have another question that I would like to get your help. I have posted it here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31116620/how-do-i-replace-the-deprecated-method-date-sethoursint?noredirect=1#comment50247785_31116620). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue while migrating my project to Java 11. Here is the answer

new Date("08/10/2020");

to

DateFormat.getDateInstance().parse("08/10/2020")

Comment: In most locales it doesn’t work.  On my Java 11 it threw an exception in 726 out of 748 available locales, and I doubt that the result was correct for all of the remaining 22 locales, which I didn’t bother to check.