# android date picker set time

Tags: android, date, datetime

i would like to set the date format of my date picker like this:

yyyy-MM-dd HH:ss:mm

I hope this is the correct format for dates in databases. if not, please tell me which format is right.

also i would like to set the hour,minute and second of selected date like 0
Example:

2015-11-30 00:00:00

For this i use this code:

```
long dateTime = DatePicker.getCalendarView().getDate();
Date date = new Date(dateTime);
date.setHours(0);
date.setMinutes(0);
date.setSeconds(0);
```

Android Studio tells me, that setHours,setMinutes and setSeconds is deprecated. what is the new way to set this values?

Comment: Its better to save time in `milliSeconds` in database.

Comment: The `Date` class is mostly deprecated now. Use a [`Calendar`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) instead.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31118035/2266087

Comment: check:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33708631/trying-to-set-text-of-edittext-from-datepicker-dialogfragment/33708665#33708665

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Calendar` Object instead of `Date`:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTimeInMillis(DatePicker.getCalendarView().getDate(););
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR,00);
```

like wise

Comment: Agreed, Calendar is the way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z'");

String dateString = "2015-11-30 00:00:00";
try {

        Date date = df.parse(dateString);
        df.applyPattern("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
        String result = df.format(date);
    }
catch (ParseException e){
                          e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```