# What is an easy way to output a stored gregorian calendar to be used output to xml

Tags: java, xml, calendar, gregorian-calendar

I'm trying to work out a better way of converting a date that is in the form of a gregorian calendar into an XML so later it is easy to get it back. I'm trying to avoid parsing the date out if I can avoid it.

The date is implemented in a class as

```
GregorianCalendar dateOfBirth;
public void setDateOfBirth(GregorianCalendar dateIn ){
    this.dateOfBirth = dateIn;
}
public GregorianCalendar getDOB(GregorianCalendar dateIn ){
    return this.dateOfBirth;
}

//To set the date of birth
newStudent.setDateOfBirth(new GregorianCalendar(dobYEAR, dobMON, dobDAY));
```

Currently I am sending the XML a string using

```
documentModel.createTextNode(thisStudent.toStringDOB());
```

Which sends a string

05/09/1984

This would be fine for a display but, when I read the XML back I want to store it as gregorian calendar. Im sure I can break it down to ints of month day and year then send those individually into the XML with something to the effect like this

```
documentModel.createTextNode(thisStudent.getDOBday().toString());
documentModel.createTextNode(thisStudent.getDOBmonth().toString());
documentModel.createTextNode(thisStudent.getDOByear().toString());
```

And when I parse the XML back in i could set a new gregorian date. But would like to do something simple like.

```
documentModel.createTextNode(thisStudent.getDOB().toString());
```

Where there would be only one item that needs to be delt with on both ends. But the toString method for calendar/gregorian calendar is not useful for the situation I need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a string to a GregorianCalendar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331513/convert-a-string-to-a-gregoriancalendar)

Comment: This article covers half of my question. Im looking for a simpler gregorian out/  gregorian In situation.