# Convert String to Calendar Object in Java

Tags: java, date, datetime, calendar, simpledateformat

I am new to Java, usually work with PHP.

I am trying to convert this string:

> Mon Mar 14 16:02:37 GMT 2011

Into a Calendar Object so that I can easily pull the Year and Month like this:

```
String yearAndMonth = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)+cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

Would it be a bad idea to parse it manually? Using a substring method?

Any advice would help thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a date String to a Date or Calendar object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43802/how-to-convert-a-date-string-to-a-date-or-calendar-object)

Answer (score 457, accepted):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
cal.setTime(sdf.parse("Mon Mar 14 16:02:37 GMT 2011"));// all done
```

note: set `Locale` according to your environment/requirement

---

**See Also**

- [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm. This is online timestamp converter. The value which is calculated by java code and this online convert gets differ. Why?? Can u pls go through this. Thanks :)

Comment: Note that this looses the timezone information. The Calendar object will have the system default TimeZone not the parsed one.

Comment: This should not be the top/accepted answer any more. Since Java 8 is already out for more than 4 years the answer should be updated to mention `java.time`. This Q/A comes up pretty prominent on google.

Answer (score 26):

## tl;dr

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes.

```
YearMonth.from(
    ZonedDateTime.parse( 
        "Mon Mar 14 16:02:37 GMT 2011" , 
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "E MMM d HH:mm:ss z uuuu" )
     )
).toString()
```

> 2011-03

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The modern way is with java.time classes. The old date-time classes such as `Calendar` have proven to be poorly-designed, confusing, and troublesome.

Define a custom formatter to match your string input.

```
String input = "Mon Mar 14 16:02:37 GMT 2011";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "E MMM d HH:mm:ss z uuuu" );
```

Parse as a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( input , f );
```

You are interested in the year and month. The java.time classes include `YearMonth` class for that purpose.

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.from( zdt );
```

You can interrogate for the year and month numbers if needed.

```
int year = ym.getYear();
int month = ym.getMonthValue();
```

But the `toString` method generates a string in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

```
String output = ym.toString();
```

Put this all together.

```
String input = "Mon Mar 14 16:02:37 GMT 2011";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "E MMM d HH:mm:ss z uuuu" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( input , f );
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.from( zdt );
int year = ym.getYear();
int month = ym.getMonthValue();
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "input: " + input );
System.out.println( "zdt: " + zdt );
System.out.println( "ym: " + ym );
```

> input: Mon Mar 14 16:02:37 GMT 2011

> zdt: 2011-03-14T16:02:37Z[GMT]

> ym: 2011-03

### Live code

See [this code running in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/WJBUzK).

### Conversion

If you *must* have a `Calendar` object, you can convert to a [`GregorianCalendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) using new methods added to the old classes.

```
GregorianCalendar gc = GregorianCalendar.from( zdt );
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the process of [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Just to add to this, one can access the Day from the `ZonedDateTime` Object. For example: `zdt.getDayOfMonth()` (returns `int`), `zdt.getDayOfYear()` (returns `int`), or `zdt.getDayOfWeek()` (returns `java.time.DayOfWeek`).

Answer (score 14):

Well, I think it would be a bad idea to replicate the code which is already present in classes like [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

On the other hand, personally I'd suggest avoiding `Calendar` and `Date` entirely if you can, and using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead, as a far better designed date and time API. For example, you need to be aware that `SimpleDateFormat` is *not* thread-safe, so you either need thread-locals, synchronization, or a new instance each time you use it. Joda parsers and formatters *are* thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I will certainly look into using Joda in the future, looks like it can be very useful

Comment: @Jon Skeet Joda will not deserialize in Android. Joda is worth little unless you have no need to save dates and time.

Comment: @FrankZappa: I'd disagree with that - you can do all your date/time *calculations* in Joda Time, but then convert to other types (maybe just strings for simplicity) for serialization purposes.

Comment: Sorry, had to downvote, the answer is too old, it's outdated to be the highest ranking answer. Today `java.time` is the way to go, Basil Bourque provided an excellent answer.

Comment: @Scolytus: The top (and accepted) answer has 332 votes compared with 10 on this one. I think if you go round downvoting every 7+-year-old answer that has a better solution now, you'll run out of downvotes... (I agree that Basil's answer is good, and I've upvoted that.)

Comment: @JonSkeet OMG, I'm sorry, I totally got the wrong answer, in fact this was intended for the top/accepted answer. Your answer with Joda time was already a better one. Really sorry!

Answer (score 10):

No new Calendar needs to be created, SimpleDateFormat already uses a Calendar underneath.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.EN_US);
Date date = sdf.parse("Mon Mar 14 16:02:37 GMT 2011"));// all done
Calendar cal = sdf.getCalendar();
```

(I can't comment yet, that's why I created a new answer)

Comment: Your solution looks elegant, but has two disadvantages: 1. The JavaDoc doesn't guarantee that the behavior is, as expected. 2. At least for Java 6 you find a path at line 1353 where the calendar-object is cloned. So then then !date.equals(cal.getTime()).

Answer (score 6):

`SimpleDateFormat` is great, just note that `HH` is different from `hh` when working with hours. `HH` will return 24 hour based hours and hh will return 12 hour based hours.

For example, the following will return 12 hour time:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
```

While this will return 24 hour time:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
```

Answer (score 6):

Parse a time with timezone, `Z` in pattern is for time zone

```
String aTime = "2017-10-25T11:39:00+09:00";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.getDefault());
try {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(sdf.parse(aTime));
    Log.i(TAG, "time = " + cal.getTimeInMillis()); 
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output: it will return the UTC time

```
1508899140000
```

[image]

If we don't set the time zone in pattern like `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`. `SimpleDateFormat` will use the time zone which have set in `Setting`

Answer (score 3):

Yes it would be bad practice to parse it yourself.  Take a look at [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), it will turn the String into a Date and you can set the Date into a Calendar instance.

Answer (score 1):

Simple method:

```
public Calendar stringToCalendar(String date, String pattern) throws ParseException {
    String DEFAULT_LOCALE_NAME = "pt";
    String DEFAULT_COUNTRY = "BR";
    Locale DEFAULT_LOCALE = new Locale(DEFAULT_LOCALE_NAME, DEFAULT_COUNTRY);
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, LocaleUtils.DEFAULT_LOCALE);
    Date d = format.parse(date);
    Calendar c = getCalendar();
    c.setTime(d);
    return c;
}
```