# changing string to Calendar object value.

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-date

I am having `string date = "2014-09-11"`.

i want to set this string to calendar object.

The string value is already having "-" in it. So how to use date formatting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse date string to Date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496359/how-to-parse-date-string-to-date)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert String to Calendar Object in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301226/convert-string-to-calendar-object-in-java)

Comment: yes it worked! It was a confusing because of parsing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a date format to parse your string

```
String dateStr = "2014-09-11";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
DateTime date = format.parse(dateStr);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String dateInString = "2014-09-11";

try {

    Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
    System.out.println(date);
    System.out.println(formatter.format(date));

} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    String date = "2014-09-11";
    String dt[]=date.split("-");
    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, Integer.parseInt(dt[2]));
    cal.add(Calendar.MONTH,Integer.parseInt(dt[1]));
    cal.add(Calendar.YEAR,Integer.parseInt(dt[0]));

    System.out.print(cal.getTime().toString());
```

Comment: It should be cal.set(), now you are adding to current calendar.
Also, Calendar.MONTH is from 0-11 so there should be -1 (when using set) there as well.