# Convert String to Calendar type and pass it as parameter to constructor in Java

Tags: java, constructor, calendar

I have a constructor like this :

Person (String name, int age, Calendar date_employment);

When i read this info from my file I get it as a String so how do I convert my String which contains my date into a Calendar type so I can pass it to my constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Why but my good lady or sir, it has already been covered! All you shall need to do is Google. [Convert String to Calendar Object in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301226/convert-string-to-calendar-object-in-java)

Comment: Thank you, I did google it but it's not quite the answer i need. The converting part works fine until i need to pass it to my constructor.

Comment: @Ivana is it throwing any error ? Post your code plz

Comment: I'm doing this

 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
cal.set(year,month,date) ;

I can't pass it to my constructor since it's not a Calendar type.
I'm looking for a solution to this.

Comment: I simplified it so the only thing i read from my file is the date : 
while ((line = flux_in.readLine()) != null)
{  
  aux = linie.split("-");

 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 cal.set(Integer.parseInt(aux[0]),Integer.parseInt(aux[1]),Integer.parseInt(aux[2]));

       pers.add(new Person(cal)); // this is where I'm having trouble 
}