# how to get current date in java in GoogleAppEngine app, and separate Day, Month and Year from that date and store it in datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, date

[below image is screenshot of my web page I am creating gae app that store some data in google datastore but having some difficulties with date format at client side i am using Anugularjs date as shown in image i want to store that date but also i want to separate day month and year of that date in java

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like on any other Java 7 system, a typical pattern (after the appropriate imports at the top of your Java code) would be:

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
int year  = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH); 
int day   = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

That's because `java.util.Date`, which used to be the natural way to do things, is mostly deprecated in Java 7 (though AFAIK it still works).

In Java 8 you'd use `java.time`, but GAE does not yet support Java 8.

Comment: thanks @Alex but i stuck with angularjs date format, how to get that date in java object and perform operations on it??

Comment: On the JS side, format the date as a string as per https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date and send it to the server as you would any other string; on the server side, parse the string back into a Calendar object as per e.g http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301226/convert-string-to-calendar-object-in-java then proceed as above to extract year etc. Neither half is really a google-app-engine question at all: best tag it as angular-js!

Comment: okay I think this might help I try this one thanks a lot @Alex

Comment: @MayurPardeshi, if the answer helps, remember to accept it (click on the checkmark outline to the left of the answer) -- fundamental stackoverflow etiquette.