# How to filter a ArrayList according to date/time and display it in a recyclerview in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, date

I have created a events list that allows users to add events, what I want to do is only display events that are not passed current date and time. I allow the user to pick a date and time which are stored as String in the format dd/MM/yy (00/00/0000) for date and HH:mm (00:00) for time in separate String variables.

I have been working on this for a nearly 3 days and still can't figure out how to do it, the concept is just on top of my head but doesn't seem to want to get out. After trying several things I have ended up with something like:

```
public void futureEvents() {
    ArrayList<Events> futureEvents = new ArrayList<>();
    long currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    Log.d("CurrentTime", String.valueOf(currentTime)); // This works fine, when I Log.d I get results like 1486243693904

    for(Events events : eventsList) {

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date date = null;
        try { // I am forced to surround date = formatter.... code in try and catch
            date = formatter.parse(events.getEventDate());
        } catch (ParseException e) {

        }

        String eventTime = events.getEventTime();
        String []tokens = eventTime.split(":");
        long longEventTime = (long) ((Long.parseLong(tokens[0]) * 3.6e+6) + (Long.parseLong(tokens[1])* 1.66667e-5));
        long eventTimeAndDateInLong = Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(longEventTime + date.getTime()));

        if(currentTime < eventTimeAndDateInLong + 30*600000) {

            futureEvents.add(events); // throws a null object reference error
        }
    }

    adapter.filter(futureEvents); 
}
```

I am not sure if it makes sense, but it surely doesn't work and as much as I don't want to give up, I am fed up with it not working after several attempts, I am fairly new to java and don't yet now my way around. I would really appreciate if someone could help.

Note. All I want is to filter out passed events and show the upcoming ones according to date and time.

Update --- Stack trace

```
02-05 11:33:47.282 19010-19010/com.example.myapp E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.myapp.SQLiteDB.EventsList_SQLDB.adapter.filter(java.util.ArrayList)' on a null object reference
                                                                          at layout.Events.upcomingEvents(Events.java:352)
                                                                          at layout.Events.onCreateView(Events.java:100)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2184)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1298)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentsToInvisible(FragmentManager.java:2323)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2136)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2092)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1969)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:620)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1268)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1116)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1642)
                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19861)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
                                                                          at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:714)
                                                                          at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
                                                                          at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1375)
                                                                          at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:784)
                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19861)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19861)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19861)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19861)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19861)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:689)
                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19861)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2275)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1366)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1619)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6343)
                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
02-05 11:33:47.282 19010-19010/com.example.myapp E/UncaughtException:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6126)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Update -- what is adapter.filter(FutureEvents)
This is a simple filter which should if the above code works fine filter out previous events. It works if I pass it other fixed parameters e..g 01/02/2017

```
public void setFilter(ArrayList<Events> filterEvents) {
        eventsLists = new ArrayList<>();
        eventsLists.addAll(filterevents);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the entire stack-trace/error output ?

Comment: Also what is 'adapter.filter()' in your code ?

Comment: Your adapter object reference is null. Can you show where you are initializing the adapter ?

Comment: Adapter adapter; This is global
adapter = new Adapter(getActivity(), EventsList); This is in oncreateview

Comment: I am using the same filter method to filter if user given date matches the date in my list and that is working.

Comment: Your stack trace clearly suggests that your adapter reference is null. You would have to post the entire code before the place you are calling futureEvents() methods

Comment: Could this be an issue I was calling the method before I actually instialised my adapter class!

Comment: That's it.! You have to initialize the obect before calling the method.

Comment: Its not throwing any errors now, opens the app but isn't displaying future events properly. It shows the same event twice, when there are two events  in the list that occur after todays date

Comment: Its working, thanks I deleted the list and re added it. Was there anything wrong with the previous code I had compared to your revised version though. Just to check if I was right or on the right track?

Comment: Your previous code would work but that's not the most elegant way to handle the problem. Check the code in my answer and decide for yourself which one is easier to understand.

Comment: Your code is neat, I just wanted to know whether I was on the right track. When I wrote that code, I had in mind what you wrote but couldn't put it to  java!. Also can I ask, you see in my code I have + 30*600000 in if(currentTime < eventTimeAndDateInLong + 30*600000) how can I use that in your code. What that does is defines a threshold and only shows events that are about to start in the next 30 minutes

Comment: @Abhishek Jain, I'll  mark it as accepted. Can I ask would you know how to define a threshold to only show events occuring in the next say 5 hours?

Comment: Check my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks, I look into that the conversion. I have another question, on a different part of my application. I assume it won't be appropriate to ask here.  Would it be all right to start a discussion with yourself for that question if you have time, it should be too difficult as I have the code there but it isn't working for some reason. Or shall I post another question.

Comment: I'd suggest you search and see if you find a similar question already asked if not, post another question.

Comment: I have already searched for it, and have come up with my own solution given what I found but that isn't working either.

Comment: Sorry, I tried accepting it earlier but it did not allow it. I accepted it know, it shows accepted on my side, could you confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Date`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html) class provides method to test if a date is [`before()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#before(java.util.Date)) or [`after()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#after(java.util.Date)) the specified date.

Also you can get a `Date` object with both date and time information and then compare it with the current Date object.

Using all this you can greatly simplify your code like this :

```
public void futureEvents() {
    ArrayList<Events> futureEvents = new ArrayList<>();
    Date currentDate = new Date();

    for(Events events : eventsList) {    
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
        Date date = null;
        try { 
            date = formatter.parse(events.getEventDate() + " " + events.getEventTime());
        } catch (ParseException e) {

        }

        if(currentDate.before(date)) {    
            futureEvents.add(events); 
        }
    }

    adapter.filter(futureEvents); 
}
```

**Edit** : The above is still applicable for your code. But looking at your stack trace, you are getting a `NullPointerException` on `adapter` reference. Your `adapter` object reference is null.
Make sure you are initialising your `adapter` object before calling `futureEvents()` method.

If you want to set threshold on either side, you can modify the current date object so that it points to the date and time which is set based on your threshold. For example if you want to filter the events that occur in the next 30 minutes you can do something like this :

```
public void futureEvents() {
    ArrayList<Events> futureEvents = new ArrayList<>();
    Date currentDate = new Date();

    for(Events events : eventsList) {    
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
        Date date = null;
        try { 
            date = formatter.parse(events.getEventDate() + " " + events.getEventTime());
        } catch (ParseException e) {

        }

        Date thresholdDate = currentDate.clone(); //makes a copy of the currentDate object
        thresholdDate.setMinutes(thresholdDate .getMinutes() + 30);//Modify minutes to 30 minutes in future.

        if(currentDate.before(date) && date.before(thresholdDate)) {    
            futureEvents.add(events); 
        }
    }

    adapter.filter(futureEvents); 
}
```

Similarly you can modify **hours, days, months** or **years**.

Comment: I have added the stack and my adapter.filter. I have a adapter class in which I have defined a filter method which is supposed to filter out all the previous events.

Comment: Thanks, I see that setMinutes is depreciated, would it be OK to use it?

Comment: @AdamBrown I would suggest ditching Date altogether. User [Calender](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) instead. Since you were using Date, I didn't want to confuse you.

Comment: @AdamBrown Check this answer to see how to convert date string to Calender object. [Convert String to Calendar Object in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5301325/3857465)