# Setting current date from ISO 8601 in object Calendar format using Java

Tags: java, calendar, datetime-parsing, java.util.calendar

Im trying to set the `Calendar` date object in the following way, but I don't know how.

```
public void setTradeDate(String tradeDate) {
    Calendar tradeDate = ?
}
```

The `String` is in the format:

```
String tradeDate = "2017-06-01T15:49:18Z";
```

Comment: @Jotunacorn, I require in Calendar format.

Comment: I don't understand what *Calendar format* might be. Do you want to get a `String` or a `Calendar` object?

Comment: @Thomas Calendar object.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch, updated my question. I guess it made you confuse.

Comment: You confused everyone. This obsoletes all 3 answers given so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a `Calendar` from a `String`, you can use a `SimpleDateFormat` (as already suggested by the other answers). The formatter will parse the `String` and create a `Date` object, which will be set to the `Calendar`:

```
String tradeDate = "2017-06-01T15:49:18Z";

// create Calendar
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
// create formatter
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");
// parse string and set the resulting date to Calendar
cal.setTime(df.parse(tradeDate));
```

The `Calendar` will contain the date equivalent to `2017-06-01T15:49:18Z`. Note that this date/time is in UTC - the `Z` in the end is the [UTC designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#UTC).

*But if you try to print this date (using `System.out.println(cal.getTime())`, a logger, or even checking its value in a debugger), it'll implicity use the `toString()` method, and this converts the fields (day, month, year, hour, minute, seconds, etc) to the system's default timezone (if your default timezone is in India, for example, the date will be printed as `Thu Jun 01 21:19:18 IST 2017`, although the internal value won't be changed). But the **value** will still be equivalent to the UTC input.*

*Don't be misleaded by the output of `toString()` method from `Calendar` and `Date` classes. What matters is the value of the timestamp: the number of milliseconds since `1970-01-01T00:00Z`, which can be checked with `cal.getTimeInMillis()`. Check [this article](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/) for more information.*

---

As you're using Java 7, there's another (better) alternative: you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes.

You can parse the input to a `org.threeten.bp.ZonedDateTime` and use the `org.threeten.bp.DateTimeUtils` class to convert it to a `java.util.Calendar`:

```
String tradeDate = "2017-06-01T15:49:18Z";
// parse input
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(tradeDate);
// convert to calendar
Calendar cal = DateTimeUtils.toGregorianCalendar(zdt);
```

Using this backport eliminates [lots of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1571265/7605325) and [design issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442/7605325) of the old `Calendar` API. And makes a future migration to Java 8 much easier, as in new Java 8 API the classes and methods names are the same, just the packages are different (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport is `org.threeten.bp`).

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to use java-8?

```
ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.now();
System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.format(dateTime));
```

Comment: Im using Java 7.. :( \

Comment: @Syed, can you then use http://www.joda.org/joda-time/ in your project?

Comment: Anton, I should get the calendar date object.

Comment: Quotes from your link, @AntonBalaniuc: “Users are now asked to migrate to `java.time` (JSR-310).” “Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project. No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate to `java.time` (JSR-310).” While Joda-Time is viable, I think that ThreeTen Backport, suggested [by Hugo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45736295/5772882) is even better.

Answer (score 0):

Read the javadoc of [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).
`'T'` will yield a literal `T`.
`X` will yield a *ISO 8601 time zone* (which is `Z` in case of UTC time zone).
So you can achieve it by:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Calendar calobj = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(df.format(calobj.getTime()));
```

The `X` is not supported before Java 7. You can use `'Z'` instead to get a literal `Z`.

Comment: Again it will be in Dateformat return type. How can I get only the calendar object type. Because I need to set the calendar object

Comment: this is my method signature and it takes calendar object. public void setTradeDate(java.util.Calendar tradeDate) { }

Comment: Actually, `X` is [supported in Java 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). It's [not supported in Java 6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), though.

Comment: Thanks @Hugo , I updated my answer.

Answer (score -1):

A possible solution is

```
public void setTradeDate(String tradeDate) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'");
    try {
        cal.setTime(df.parse(tradeDate));
    } catch(ParseException e) {
        //Handle exception
    }
    System.out.println(cal); //Change to setting the field instead.
}
```

use it by callling

```
setTradeDate("2017-06-01T15:49:18Z");
```

Comment: I require in Calendar return type.. Please read my question

Comment: I've read your question and as I understand it the current
    System.out.println(df.format(calobj.getTime()));
prints on the wrong format. The solution to this is to change the format as I instructed. What do you mean by "I require Calendar return type"?

Comment: public void setTradeDate(java.util.Calendar tradeDate) { }.. My method takes calendar object in that format.

Comment: DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'");
  System.out.println(df.format(tradeDate.getTime()))

Comment: @Jotunacom, you are getting my point wrong.. I have sent the signature to tell u that I require 2017-06-01T15:49:18Z as Calendar object so that I can set in that method.

Comment: So what you want to do is convert a String time to a calendar?

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'");
cal.setTime(df.parse("2017-06-01T15:49:18Z"))

see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301226/convert-string-to-calendar-object-in-java

Comment: Please test your code again. There is parseException