# How to convert date/time strings into Java Calendar objects?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert a date String to a Date or Calendar object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43802/how-to-convert-a-date-string-to-a-date-or-calendar-object)

I'm in a pinch here...

I have a series of date/time strings formatted like this:"9-29-2011 9:05 PM PDT"
and I need to convert this string into a java Calendar object.
Once I have this Calendar object it must represent exactly this
date and time (including the AM or PM). Please, what is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Use [DateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) to parse the `String`. Pass the `Date` to the `Calendar.setTime()` method.

Answer (score -1):

Check out http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/ . Joda Time makes a lot of tricky date/time operations simple!

You will probably want to construct a custom formatter: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#Input_and_Output

`DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a z");` should be close. You can then convert the Joda DateTime to Date or to a Calendar.

Comment: why would this be down voted? Sure you can do the same with built in classes, but i don't see where this is a bad answer.

Comment: Freiheit thanks. I knew nothing of Joda Time. Grateful for your input...