# "Unparseable date" when trying to convert "16 Nov 2011 08:00" string to Date?

Tags: java, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert a date String to a Date or Calendar object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43802/how-to-convert-a-date-string-to-a-date-or-calendar-object)

How can I convert `"16 Nov 2011 08:00"` to a Date object? I tried `SimpleDateFormat` but does not works, I get

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "16 Nov 2011 08:00"

or will I have to split the string enter slashes and then give it a try ?

Comment: What date is that supposed to represent?  A `Date` represents a single point in time, not a period.  Also, with `SimpleDateFormat` you give it a custom format.  It would obviously be relevant what format you're giving it.

Comment: There's a pretty significant difference between your question's **title**  and its **body**.

Comment: Sorry guys, I surely know that I cannot convert time range in a Date object, there was mistake in the question I have updated it, thanks for Input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You problem with the SimpleDateFormat was probably an incorrect format string.

Here is the correct way:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm" );
Date date = formatter.parse( "16 Nov 2011 08:00" );
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `SimpleDateFormat` to set a date format then use `.parse(String s)` to convert your `String` to a `Date`, here's an example:

```
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm");
    String theDateString = "16 Nov 2011 08:00";
    Date myDate = format.parse(theDateString);
```