# How to place a date-time string into a Calendar object?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert a date String to a Date or Calendar object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43802/how-to-convert-a-date-string-to-a-date-or-calendar-object)

How could I do something like this

```
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar("2012-08-02 12:04:03");
```

or

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setDateTime("2012-08-02 12:04:03");
```

**NOTE**: The code snippets above are not actually possible, I would like to mock that behavior.

**Further Clarification**

Suppose I have a date and time string like "2012-08-02 12:04:03". Is there an efficient way of getting this information into a Calendar object without manually breaking it up into month, year, and day strings then converting them to integers then calling set(Calendar.HOUR) etc?

Currently, I have a form that takes as input the year, month, hour, day, and so on and I pass those individually into a calendar object but it would be nice if I could use a single date and time string like "2012-08-02 12:04:03"

Comment: use this instead joda-time http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @JBNizet Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Downvoting because it's a duplicate? Shame on the culprit. It's not like I can delete the post once people have answered....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    String dateString=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse("2012-08-02 12:04:03");
            Calender cal = Calender.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(dateString).getTime());
```

wrap it around try catch though as the parse method would throw ParseException. and study the link provided by @user714965

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) which gives you a `Date` object. With that `Date` object you can initialize your `Calendar`

Comment: I know you can use SimpleDateFormat to format the output of Calendar object but how would you use it configure the input?

Comment: See the [parse()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

**Use .parse() method to convert the String to Date object:**

`String dateString=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse("2012-08-02 12:04:03");`

**getInstance() will create an instance of one of the Subclass of the abstract Calendar class:**

`Calender cal = Calender.getInstance();`

**setTime() will take a Date object:**

`cal.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").fomat(dateString).getTime());`