# How to convert a numeric value to date in Java?

Tags: java, date

I have a list of values `12012`, `112013` , `52005` stored as strings and i need to convert them into Jan 2012, Nov 2013, May 2005 correspondingly. I know how I can do this using parsing the string and using the `if` statement. Is there any efficient way?

Comment: Check out `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a date String to a Date or Calendar object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43802/how-to-convert-a-date-string-to-a-date-or-calendar-object)

Comment: https://google.com/search?q=java+convert+string+to+date has as 1st hit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have strings representing dates that have two different formats Myyyy and MMyyyy, with a `SimpleDateFormat` I'm not sure you can avoid an if statement, that's how I would do it:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("Myyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMyyyy");
    Date d = null;
    if(5 == s.length()){
        d = sdf1.parse(s);
    }else if(6 == s.length()){
        d = sdf2.parse(s);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like this might work:

```
String val = "12012";
int numVal = Integer.parseInt(val);
int year = numVal % 10000;
int month = numVal / 10000;
... create a date from that ...
```

I don't know whether you want a java `Date` or `Calendar` or whatever.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance().clear();
cal.set(year, month-1, 1);

Date date = cal.getTime();
```

Or Joda Time for a date without a timezone:

```
LocalDate dt = new LocalDate(year, month, 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Using SimpleDateFormat pattern you can easily do that: Try following simple code:

```
String str="12012";//112013 , 52005
SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("Myyyy");
SimpleDateFormat resFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("MMM yyyy");
Date date=format.parse(str);
System.out.println(resFormat.format(date));
```

Comment: I'm not sure this would work as you have two types of dates given in the example Myyyy and MMyyyy, if you try your solution with 112013 it will print : jan. 12013 instead of nov 2013