# How to pass "yyyy-mm-dd" format date to calender control in Java?

Tags: java, date

i have a string with "yyyy-MM-dd" date format and i want to pass it to a calender control in java. the way i am doing is giving me a wrong answer Please Help

```
String da = "1957-01-01"
Date date = Date.parse(da);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);
```

I am getting a output such as Tuesday, April 12, 1952 AD or 3:30:42pm PST[Example]

Comment: Your code not even compile.

Comment: Don't use `Date.parse`, which has been deprecated for *ages*. Use `SimpleDateFormat`. And for *output*, you presumably need to set the format on the control - but we don't have *any clue* what kind of control it is, or even what kind of user interface this is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a date String to a Date or Calendar object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43802/how-to-convert-a-date-string-to-a-date-or-calendar-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
String da = "1957-01-01";
DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date=df.parse(da); // parse your string to date 
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);
System.out.println(df.format(calendar.getTime())); // format date
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the date a format first:

```
String da = "1957-01-01"
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(da);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SimpleDateformat for this

```
String strFormat="yyyy/MM/dd"; 
    DateFormat myDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(strFormat);
    Date myDate = new Date();
    Calendar calender=new Calender();

    myDate = myDateFormat.parse("2007/05/12");
    myGDate.setTime(myDate);
```

Comment: Your date formatter is wrong month should be `MM` not `mm`. `mm` for minutes.